# ControllerGetCapabilities can this be called as a client to get supported capabilities of a csi driver

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-csi

```
// ControllerGetCapabilities implements the default GRPC callout.
func (csiCS *CSIControllerServer) ControllerGetCapabilities(ctx context.Context, req *csi.ControllerGetCapabilitiesRequest) (*csi.ControllerGetCapabilitiesResponse, error) {
```

Is there a way a to check particular version of CSI controller driver supports snapshot or not.